# Calendaring Monthly Usages for each Date

Tags: r, function, datetime, sum, aggregate

Here, i have a data set with Start date and End Date and the usages. I have calculated the number of Days between these two days and got the daily usages. (I am okay with one flat usages for each day for now).

Now, what i want to achieve is the sum of the usage for each day in those TIME-FRAME FOR month of June. For example, the first case will be just the Daily_usage

```
START_DATE     END_DATE          x     DAYS    DAILY_USAGE
1 2015-05-01  2015-06-01    261605.00   32     8175.156250
```

And, for 2nd, i want to the add the Usage 3905 to June 1st, and also to June 2nd because it spans in both June 1st and June 2nd.

```
2015-05-04 2015-06-02   117159.00   30   3905.3000000
```

I want to continue doing this for all 387 rows and at the end get the sum of Usages for each day. And,I do not know how to do this for hundreds of records. 
This is what my datasets looks right now:

```
 str(YYY)
'data.frame':   387 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ START_DATE : Date, format: "2015-05-01" "2015-05-04" "2015-05-11" "2015-    05-13" ...
 $ END_DATE   : Date, format: "2015-06-01" "2015-06-01" "2015-06-01" "2015-06-01" ...
 $ x          : num  261605 1380796 183 103 489 ...
 $ DAYS       : num  32 29 22 20 19 12 1 34 30 29 ...
 $ DAILY_USAGE: num  8175.16 47613.66 8.32 5.13 25.74 ...
```

Also, the header.

```
START_DATE   END_DATE           x DAYS    DAILY_USAGE
1   2015-05-01 2015-06-01   261605.00   32   8175.1562500
2   2015-05-04 2015-06-01  1380796.00   29  47613.6551724
6   2015-05-21 2015-06-01     1392.00   12    116.0000000
7   2015-06-01 2015-06-01     2503.00    1   2503.0000000
8   2015-04-30 2015-06-02        0.00   34      0.0000000
9   2015-05-04 2015-06-02   117159.00   30   3905.3000000
10  2015-05-05 2015-06-02   193334.00   29   6666.6896552
13  2015-05-04 2015-06-03      630.00   31     20.3225806
```

and so on........

**Example of data sets and Results**

I will call this data set. EXAMPLE1 (For 3 days, mocked up data)

```
START_DATE  END_DATE    x   DAYS    DAILY_USAGE
5/1/2015    6/1/2015    261605  32  8175.15625
5/4/2015    6/1/2015    1380796 29  47613.65517
5/11/2015   6/1/2015    183     22  8.318181818
4/30/2015   6/2/2015    0       34  0
5/20/2015   6/2/2015    70      14  5
6/1/2015    6/2/2015    569     2   284.5
6/1/2015    6/3/2015    582     3   194
6/2/2015    6/3/2015    6       2   3
```

For the above examples, answer should be like this

```
DAY        USAGE
6/1/2015    56280.6296
6/2/2015    486.5
6/3/2015    197
```

HOW?
In Example 1, for June 1st, i have added all the rows of usages except the last row usage because the last row doesn't include the the date 06/01 in time-frame. It starts in 06/02 and ends in 06/03.

To get June 2nd, i have added all the usages from Row 4 to 8 because June 2nd is between all of those start and end dates.

For June 3rd, i have only added, Last two rows to get 197.

So, where to sum, depends on the time-frame of Start & End_date.

Hope this helps!

There might be a easy trick to do this than to write 400 lines of If else statement.

Thank you again for your time!!

-Gyve

Comment: cumsum will not give me the result i am looking for. if i do cumsum(NIDR_FINAL$x), my June 1st  will remain as it is. But, as we go below the rows, each of those time frame might give me usages, that should be added to June 1st.  As per lapply, i am not sure how to implement that in this situation. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Post what the data frame should look like from the example.

Comment: I have posted a mock up example sets to describe how the sum should happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
indx <- lapply(unique(mdy(df[,2])), '%within%', interval(mdy(df[,1]), mdy(df[,2])))
cbind.data.frame(DAY=unique(df$END_DATE), 
                 USAGE=unlist(lapply(indx, function(x) sum(df$DAILY_USAGE[x]))))
#        DAY    USAGE
# 1 6/1/2015 56280.63
# 2 6/2/2015   486.50
# 3 6/3/2015   197.00
```

---

**Explanation**

We can expand it to explain what is happening:

```
indx <- lapply(unique(mdy(df[,2])), '%within%', interval(mdy(df[,1]), mdy(df[,2])))
```

The unique end dates are tested to be within the range days in the first and second columns. `mdy` is a quick way to convert to `POSIXct` with lubridate. The operator `%within%` tests a date against an interval. We created intervals with `interval('col1', 'col2')`. This creates an index that we can subset the data by.

In our final data frame,

```
cbind.data.frame(DAY=unique(df$END_DATE),
```

creates the first column of dates.

And,

```
 USAGE=unlist(lapply(indx, function(x) sum(df$DAILY_USAGE[x])))
```

takes the sum of `df$DAILY_USAGE` by the index that we created.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to understand your answers and trying to replicate to see if i get the results.  Is there a reason why we converted date back to the POSIXct?  Also, the index you created is all TRUE/FALSE values, TRUE if END DATE is between both Start & End date. correct?

Comment: I did the conversion just in case your dates were just strings. The index is all TRUE and FALSE values.